# Replace start and end element php

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a text and I want to replace

```
_ By italic tag <i> </i>
@ By bold tag <strong> </strong>
* Per bold and italic label


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "_Integer lacinia sed justo ac imperdiet._" Etiam gravida purus a ex fermentum, in *molestie tellus iaculis*. Nulla facilisi. Sed vel consequat eros, non sodales turpis. _Vestibulum a ligula malesuada, dapibus massa gravida, convallis nulla_. @Maecenas@ fermentum felis in *ultricies* venenatis. @Maecenas@ non commodo lectus.
```

Any help with any function?
Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid I dont understand what you are asking, please have another try! Maybe write the question in Google Translate in your language and then post the English translation here

Comment: so you like to wrap the string where start with symbol and finish with same simbol in element ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using regex. For example:

```php
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "_Integer lacinia sed justo ac imperdiet._" Etiam gravida purus a ex fermentum, in *molestie tellus iaculis*. Nulla facilisi. Sed vel consequat eros, non sodales turpis. _Vestibulum a ligula malesuada, dapibus massa gravida, convallis nulla_. @Maecenas@ fermentum felis in *ultricies* venenatis. @Maecenas@ non commodo lectus.';


$replacedText = preg_replace(
    [
        '~_([^_]+)_~sU',
        '~@([^@]+)@~sU',
        '~\*([^*]+)\*~sU',
    ],
    [
        '<i>$1</i>',
        '<strong>$1</strong>',
        '<strong><i>$1</i></strong>',
    ],
    $text
);

echo($replacedText);

/**
 * Output:
 *
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "<i>Integer lacinia sed justo ac imperdiet.</i>"
 * Etiam gravida purus a ex fermentum, in <strong><i>molestie tellus iaculis</i></strong>. Nulla facilisi.
 * Sed vel consequat eros, non sodales turpis. <i>Vestibulum a ligula malesuada, dapibus massa gravida,
 * convallis nulla</i>. <strong>Maecenas</strong> fermentum felis in <strong><i>ultricies</i></strong>
 * venenatis. <strong>Maecenas</strong> non commodo lectus.
 */
```

Comment: Solved, this does the function I wanted. Many thanks